# i am having this error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, jupyter

```
dict1={('david','mwambali','mukengane',1996): 21,
       ('donbeni',2003): 3.3 ,
       ('john',2010): 7}
to_remove=[]
for i in dict1:
    if((i[1]) <  (2000):
        to_remove.append(i)
```

i am having  this error TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: You need `i[-1]` in your `if` statement. The year is not in the second place but in the last place, because some of your keys are longer than 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [109]: dict1={('david','mwambali','mukengane',1996): 21,
     ...:        ('donbeni',2003): 3.3, 
     ...:        ('john',2010): 7}
     ...:        
In [110]: for i in dict1:
     ...:     print(i[1])
     ...:     
mwambali
2010
2003
```

Do I need to explain further?  `'mwambali'<2000` is the problem.

Comment: dict1={('david','mwambali','mukengane',1996):21,('donbeni',2003):3.3,('john',2010):7}
to_remove=[]
for i in dict1:
    if(i[1] < 2000):
        to_remove.append(i)  this what i have, so i don't understand why the sign< is the problem i will be glad to get the answer hpaulj

Comment: @DavidMwambali, Is that string comparison True or False?